# Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 problems

Tags: internet

So there's no way that my elementary will connect to wifi, i've seen similar issues saying that they had terrible Internet speed but i can't even connect and there's about 3 solutions for the problems with this driver.

Checking if it is hardware or software blocked, mine is neither

Checking if power save mode is on, mine is not

Creating a .conf file in etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf with a line saying options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 ; also didn't work

I can't get an ethernet cable connection so i can't update my kernel, also if you need me to post the output of a command i would appreciate if you told me exactly what part should i look for since i can't paste anything, i'm writing this on my cellphone.

I apologize for any mistakes in my english since it is not my mother language

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the driver by running:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```